# Displaying names of countries/cities in russian language openstreetmap

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, cartography

I'm trying to implement maps service in my project. The project is focused to russian-speaking countries. But in future I hope to expand audience. The problem is that different services show different names.

OSM shows local names- for example Chinese towns are not clear for me. Google maps shows - user sees all names in the world in his native language: if a'm russian I can see all names in russian lunguage, including names of streets in USA for example. But Google maps costs a lot for me now.

How to solve the problem and what free/cheap services did you use? Сartography isn't the main feature in the project but important.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but may be of some help. There are two ways of approaching the problem using OpenStreetMap data. 1. Russian names are sometimes provided: the tag is name:ru. However, there are very few of them. They're mostly for countries and major cities. For example, London has name:ru=Лондон. 2. But if you want everything which doesn't have a name:ru to appear in the Cyrillic alphabet, you'll have to transliterate from the most convenient source: the local name if it's in some easily transliterable script like Roman or Greek; or the English name (say) if not.

So, taking the second approach, the way I would do it would be to download the OSM data and pre-process it, inserting a transliterated name:ru where one did not exist, then render the map (using, for example, Mapnik, which is free), using a style sheet modified to use name:ru, where available, for all labels.

This, however, is an off-line solution. I realise that you probably want something on-line. Perhaps you could use Mapbox with on-line vector tiles, again pre-processed in some way before they are rendered.